# osmnx - graph_from_place gives error "no arguments in initialization list"

Tags: python-3.x, osmnx

Need to download OSM data for Manhattan region

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

place_name = "Manhattan, New York, USA"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(graph)
```

Should plot a graph of drivable streets

Answer (score 0):

This is an installation issue with a dependency. It is discussed and resolved [on GitHub](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/251).